# Couldn't find Course with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested resource, and Im trying to create a form with the nested resource. The new page works, but when I try to access the show I get the error in the title on the . Here is my code:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :courses do
  resources :lessons, shallow:true
end
```

**lessons_controller.rb**

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_lesson, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter(:get_course)

  # GET /lessons
  # GET /lessons.json
  def index
    @lessons = Lesson.all
  end

  # GET /lessons/1
  # GET /lessons/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /lessons/new
  def new
    @lesson = Lesson.new
  end

  # GET /lessons/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /lessons
  # POST /lessons.json
  def create
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
  @lesson = Lesson.new(:course=>@course)



    respond_to do |format|
      if @lesson.save
        format.html { redirect_to @lesson, notice: 'Lesson was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @lesson }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @lesson.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /lessons/1
  # PATCH/PUT /lessons/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @lesson.update(lesson_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @lesson, notice: 'Lesson was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @lesson }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @lesson.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /lessons/1
  # DELETE /lessons/1.json
  def destroy
    @lesson.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to lessons_url, notice: 'Lesson was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_lesson
      @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
    end

def get_course
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def lesson_params
      params.require(:lesson).permit(:code, :course_id)
    end
end
```

Let me know if I need to add anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the log file entry for the error with the params?

Comment: Post your `rake routes`

Comment: `before_action :get_course, except: :index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I try to access the show

Presumably, since you have defined `shallow: true` in the routes.rb you are making a request to something like `/lessons/1`. Note the order of the filters:

```
 before_action :set_lesson, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_filter(:get_course)
```

Filters run in the order that they are defined. In this case the `set_lesson` filter runs before the `get_course` filter. When the `get_course` filter is executed, it will try to find the course_id in the params hash. In the case of a "shallow" route, that parameter is not present, so `params[:course_id]` will be `nil`. Thus

`Course.find(params[:course_id])`

raises an exception.

For a "shallow" route, the ID of the nested resource (the lesson) is all that is required. Change the course filter to exclude the show action:

`before_filter :get_course, except: :show`

or don't use shallow routes.

Also, `before_action` is preferred to `before_filter`.